# List<RealmObjects> Como puedo crear un objeto de Lista con Realm Database?

Tags: android, realm

estoy intentando crear una lista de objetos de realm, pero al correr la App me manda un error que List no esta soportado cuando utilizo un objeto realm. Esta es mi clase. No he logrado compilar mi código agradezco su cualquier ayuda.

```
public class UnitDb extends RealmObject implements Parcelable, Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public String unitNumber;
    public List<ContainerDB> containers; //ContainerDB es un Obejto Realm

     public List<ContainerDB> getContainers() {
        return containers;
    }

    public void setContainers(List<ContainerDB> containers) {
        this.containers = containers;
    }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Realm no se puede utilizar ni ArrayList ni List pues estas generando un objeto con propiedades de entidad de base de datos, es por eso que no reconoce esa lista.

Para implementar listas, usa RealmList

```
public class UnitDb extends RealmObject implements Parcelable, Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public String unitNumber;
    public RealmList<ContainerDB> containers; //ContainerDB es un Obejto Realm

     public RealmList<ContainerDB> getContainers() {
        return containers;
    }

    public void setContainers(RealmList<ContainerDB> containers) {
        this.containers = containers;
    }
```

Comment: Entiendo estoy probando el código de RealmList  y por lo menos ya me compila muchas gracias